# How to take a map and use it as values in spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a spring-boot application and trying to use properties defined in a map as values that can be injected into various services. The code I am working with defines an object `PropertyLoader` which is able to return a map based on an environment. It looks something like this:

```
public interface PropertyLoader {
    public Map<String, String> load(String env);
}
```

How can I make the entries in the map returned by this method available in `@Value` injections in spring components.

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom application listener that will override default properties.

**Old answer - below is a better way to achieve it**

```
public class PropertyInjector implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        final ConfigurableEnvironment environment = event.getEnvironment();
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        //inject properties here
        props.put("key", "value");
        final PropertiesPropertySource propertySource = new PropertiesPropertySource("propertySource", props);
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(propertySource);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** - I have found better way that easily works with @Value annotation

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("some_dynamic_key", "some_dynamic_value");
        final PropertiesPropertySource propertySource = new PropertiesPropertySource("propertySource", props);
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(props);
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }

    @Value("${some_dynamic_key}")
    String property;
}
```

In such way value `some_dynamic_key` is available along all the application

Comment: Since @Value will be processed during applicationcontext starting, i'm not sure you can perform this kind of replacement dynamically. 
But if you really want to another option can be instead having @value on your fields, create a method where you fetch the value everytime you need it.
```java

Comment: @EFOE Unfortunately the `@Value` usage is in a dependency that I cannot change.

Comment: A PropertySource seems like the right answer. I'm wondering if it could be added to my `@Configuration` as a `@Bean` rather than added in a listener.

Comment: I have found a better way that easily works with @Value annotation. Please refer original answer. I Believe now it suits your needs ; )

Comment: Hi @JohnMercier. Is the given solution meets your needs?

Comment: I would have to check since the update. The original did not work for me. What I have found is a class that extends `SpringBootContextLoader` and overrides `getSpringApplication`. It then calls `context.setDefaultProperties`.